# regex look ahead quantifier

Tags: regex

I want to match the last `b` that is preceded by `aa` from the string `ababaaabaab`.

My regex: `(?<=a{2})b`

But it matches the **third** `b` which is preceded by `aaa`.

I am a beginner.

Comment: You SAY "*b that is followed by aa*" but then you try a regex that delivers "*aa that is followed by b*".  Which is it?  The third b is PRECEDED by aaa, not followed by...

Comment: Also, what tool / regular expression engine are you using?  If it happens to be one that allows variable length lookbehinds, simply put a greedy ^.* just before the a and let it consume everything up to the final aab.

Comment: Hi Sanzida, what is your actual intent here? Match the last `b`? Like `.*(?<=a{2})\Kb`? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eHYPD2/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew all **b** that is preceded by aa. if abaabcaaabaab is a string I want to match second and last b.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/udMGF7/1, so the solution below will work for you. Have you checked it yet?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't understand this  (?<=(?<!a) part of regex. Though Mr . Ryszard explain it I can't understand why need this . Could you please briefly explain it to me?

Comment: @Sanzida `(?<=a{2})` matches a location that is immediately preceded with two `a`s, but it does not check if there are any more `a`s before those two `a`s. The additional `(?<!a)` is required to make sure there are only 2 `a`s before the current location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```js
(?<=(?<!a)a{2})b
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/pTRiIE/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      a                        'a'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    a{2}                     'a' (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  b                        'b'
```

Comment: This does match the last `b` as OP attempts.